# While Loop Not Breaking In Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a program like this:

```
def read():
    while True:
        for line in temp1:
            if event in line:
                print temp1.next()
            elif date in line:
                print temp1.next()
            elif ending in line:
                print 'End of file'
                break
event = '1'
date = '2'
ending = '3'
temp1 = open('test.txt')
```

And test.txt looks like this:

```
1
ABC
2
CAB
3
```

The program outputs this:

```
ABC
CAB
```

And then it goes into an infinite loop.
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Is the text file separated line by line? Or is it all one line or comma separated? Also, please post the output of the code before it runs into an infinite loop.

Comment: The `break` is breaking out of the for loop, not the while loop.

Comment: Yes it is separated line by line, The format didn't come out

Comment: you know, you can use a debug for that.

Comment: Is `event = '1'` etc supposed to be inside the `read` function? Also, the code you posted doesn't call the `read()` function. Please fix your code so that it's a [mcve].

Comment: Although `while 1` is understood, `while True` is typically better for clarity.

Comment: Although Blckknght has answered your question you should still fix it up so that it's more useful to future readers.

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `break` statement only breaks out of the `for` loop (if it's hit). It doesn't, and indeed, can't break out of the `while` loop as well. Though I'm not sure what the `while` loop is there for, since the `for` loop should iterate over the whole file. Since you're already in a function, you can use a `return` statement to break out of multiple loops (though it would probably be better to just get rid of the extra loop).

Answer (score 0):

Add a second break statement on the line after the first break statement, but line it up with your for statement.